# Meteor Cordova FileTransfer.download error CONNECTION_ERR

Tags: cordova, meteor

I am trying to download a file from an external server and save it locally to an andriod's device storage. I am using:

```
var downloadFile = function () {

    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fs) {
        var dir = fs.root.getDirectory("appImages", {create: true, exclusive: false}, function (dirEntry) {
            var file = dirEntry.getFile("image.png", {create: true, exclusive: false}, function (fileEntry) {
                var filePath = fileEntry.toURL();
                var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
                console.log('starting file download: ' + "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" + ' to ' + filePath);
            fileTransfer.download(
                "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png",
                filePath,
                function () {
                    console.log('save');
                },
                function (error) {
                    console.log('failed to save image: ' + filePath + ' (error: ' + error.http_status + ')');
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
                },
                true
            );
            });
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        });
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    });

};
```

I get the error:

```
I20150303-14:44:20.104(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/test.js:55) starting file download: https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png to file:///storage/emulated/0/appImages/image.png
I20150303-14:44:20.104(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/test.js:69) failed to save image: file:///storage/emulated/0/appImages/image.png (error: 401)
I20150303-14:44:20.104(-7) (android:http://meteor.local/test.js:70) {"code":3,"source":"https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png","target":"file:///storage/emulated/0/appImages/image.png","http_status":401,"body":null,"exception":null}
```

The file path is created and I can browse to `/appImages` and see that there is a broken `image.png`. In my `AndroidManifest.xml` I also have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /
```

My device is also connected to the internet. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem drove me nuts but I finally figured it out. I was using a version of file-transfer that didn't play well with meteor. The version that didnt work was `0.5.0` instead I used version `0.4.3` and everything now works great,

Removed : `meteor remove cordova:org.apache.cordova.file-transfer@0.5.0`

Added : `meteor add cordova:org.apache.cordova.file-transfer@0.4.3`

Everything now works as suspected.

Answer (score 0):

There are few reasons for this problem.

1- No internet connection or connected to wifi.

2- No internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but both are present.